# Maven Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain

Tags: amazon-web-services, maven, amazon-s3

I am trying to pull down a maven project that uses AWS. I have an aws IAM user with a key and password. I ran aws configure and configured the ~/.aws/credentials file in the default account. However, when I run maven clean install, I get the following error:

```
Failed to execute goal on project project-name: 
Could not resolve dependencies for project com.project:project-name:war:1.0: 
Failed to collect dependencies at com.project:commons-java:jar:1.0.0: 
Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.project:commons-java:jar:1.0.0: 
Could not transfer artifact com.project:commons-java:pom:1.0.0 
from/to project-maven-repo-releases (s3://project-maven-repo/releases): 
Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
```

Clearly, maven cannot load the dependancies from s3. I have confirmed that my IAM user has s3 permissions. And, even though s3 is "regionless", I have supplied the correct region to the IAM account. I also have tried exporting the AWS variables to no avail. Any idea what could be the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem, have you found any solution in the end?

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with what appears to be the same issue for a while. After checking my permissions in AWS and going through a variety of other troubleshooting steps, I think my issue was resolved through changing the directory permissions for a number of different files in the build path and repo that I was trying to build. I had inadvertently cloned them and copied them over as "root", such that, even with sudo permissions, maven was failing to read my Amazon credentials.

Another step you can take to narrow down the issue is to determine where the fault lies. I accomplished this by downloading the [AWS python sample](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-python-sample), which will attempt to create and add to a bucket in your s3. If this works, that means that the problem is with maven, and your credentials can be accessed by other applications just fine, and that you have the correct permissions as far as s3 is concerned. If the python sample also doesn't work, it is easier to get into and debug where exactly the issue is (in my opinion).

Answer (score 1):

If mvn doesn't pick the aws credentials from ~/.aws/credentials, then it can be explicitly set in .m2/settings.xml . Worked for me on fedora.

```
    <settings>
        <servers>
            <server>
                <id>maven-repository2</id>
                <username><AWS_ACCESS_ID></username>
                <password><AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY></password>
            </server>
        </servers>
    </settings>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideal way is to use the $user/.aws/credentials file and set up the credentails shown in the way below

```
[default]
region = <region>
aws_access_key_id=<accesskey>
aws_secret_access_key=<secret>
```

You will get these in the image shown below in
**AWS->IAM->Security Credentials->AccessKeys**
[image]

Also your account should have access to the S3 Repository(Other dedicated permissions and policies also exists, but you should atleast have read permissions for your maven repo in S3)
[image]

If still the issue exists. Configure the security credentials in **$user/.m2/settings.xml**

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
<localRepository/>
<interactiveMode/>
<offline/>
<pluginGroups/>
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>aws-maven-repository</id>
        <username>accessKey</username>
        <password>secret</password>
    </server>
</servers>
<mirrors/>
<proxies/>
<profiles/>
<activeProfiles/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the [maven extension `aws-maven`](https://github.com/VorTECHsa/aws-maven?tab=readme-ov-file), which is able to get aws credentials from environment variables.

It allows me to use not only static (long living) aws credentials, but also short-living credentials obtained via assume-role. In such case the session token must be used together with access key ID and secret access key.
IMHO it is not possible to put session token in `settings.xml`.

Here is my script obtaining temporary credentials from AWS and calling `mvn` with these credentials. I hope it will help to somebody:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

roleArn="$(aws configure get role_arn)"
awsResponse="$(aws sts assume-role --role-arn "$roleArn" --role-session-name maven)"
envScript="$(jq -r '"export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=" + .Credentials.AccessKeyId + "\nexport AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=" + .Credentials.SecretAccessKey + "\nexport AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=" + .Credentials.SessionToken + "\n"' <<<"$awsResponse")"
eval "$envScript"

mvn dependency:resolve
```

The script uses [`jq` executable](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to convert json response from AWS to shell script.